# Is it possible in COD:BlackOps PS3 identify who is the "host"?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops

Sometimes when I play Blackops, I get a "host migration". I am assuming that it's because someone who was "hosting" a session has dropped out. I notice that it tends to happen when I am doing really well :(

If this is the case, then is it possible to identify who is the host ? If I can see the host, I can make a cal whether to particpate or not.

Comment: Could the host be sad that you've been doing really good? (joking)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (now defunct) COD4 Board forums gave a few hints on determining your host:

> 1. If you are the first person to enter an empty lobby, you are the
>      host.
> 2. Right when the match finishes loading and the countdown begins,
>      press select and check the
>      connections. If you have a 4 bar
>      connection and everyone has red bars,
>      and a little green plug icon next to
>      their rank, that means they are
>      connecting to you and you are the
>      host. Now if only 2 or 3 of them have
>      the little plug thing, you aren't the
>      host.
> 3. If you are the only person who has a 4 bar connection the whole match,
>      you are the host.

Other posts also said that it's basically the person with the most (4 or 5) bars in their connection.

Answer (score 1):

Set your clan tag to %. If you are host, the % will stay as %. If you are not host it will change to a period. Easiest way

Comment: Good if I want to know if I am the host, but only works if everyone else does it to.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to find out if you're the host, is if you get disconnected immediately when you throw your lag switch.

Let's be real here- that's why you're asking. So you can cheat.

If you're the host, pressing the switch just for a couple seconds won't boot you.

If you're not the host, it will.

Answer (score -2):

The host generally has the best connection in the game.

Comment: -1 This does not sufficently answer the question, and the host could have a bad internet connection.

Comment: -1 Doesn't answer question.

Comment: The game chooses the person with the best Internet connection and they are selected as the host. So my answer is sufficient enough tyvm.

Comment: The problem is with the other 10% of the time. If only 90% the host has the best connection, how can you possiblly know whether or not the person with the best connection is the host?